# IntelliJ IDEA not responding to mouse clicks

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a problem with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6. 
 Everything works fine, as long as I have only one project (one window) opened. When I open second/third etc. project, only the first one responds to mouse clicks. 
Every other project reacts to keyboard input (Ctrl+TAB, Alt+arrows etc.), but not to mouse input. I'm able to modify code, use keystrokes, so the application is not frozen.
I tried to reinstall the app, no effect. The last update was a couple of weeks ago and the problem appeared today.
I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Has anyone here encountered similar problem?

Oh, and is there some magical place, where log files are stored?

Comment: I have the same issue while using pycharm community edition...

Comment: I also have mouse issues on intellij.  I'm using a touchpad and right click is not working when in Intellij.  I have Ubuntu 20.04.  I only have one monitor.

Comment: Had checked here was a memory leak after heavy  apps. Also before have changed JAVA_HOME value to higher  than jdk9 versions. After pointing to 9 and reboot it opens now

Comment: after wasting and struggling of 2 weeks, almost muted my work on intellij, whatever suggestions and permutation and combination didn't work. Finally changed to apple mouse from Logitec mouse did the trick.

Answer (score 17):

I had similar problems like you describe. It's a compatibility problem between IDEA and systems using Gnome (I don't know about KDE), there's probably nothing you can do at the moment to fix it for good, however **minimizing/rezising the IDEA window with that project fixed it for me**. Try it out if this workaround also works for you.

Comment: Well it doesn't solve the problem, but I noticed an interesting thing. I'm using dual monitor, and the problem starts, when two projects are on different screens. When all project windows are started on one screen, the problem does not occur - it starts, when at least one of the projects is moved to the second screen.

Comment: I am using dual monitors also.. This might be important.. What happens if you move the unresponsive window to the primary screen click on it and then move it to the secondary?

Comment: As long as all the windows are opened on one screen and stay on one screen, the problem does not occur. Moving any window to second screen causes the problem. To get rid of it I have to close other projects. When there is only one project remaining, it works properly, whether it was earlier blocked or not.

Comment: Hmm.. this is wierd. My problems were fixed by what I mentioned. Maybe someone else can shed some light.

Comment: The problem occasionally happens for me and my colleagues regardless of single or dual monitor. Sometimes it stops processing keyboard events, sometimes stops mouse events, sometimes both. `kill -9` is the only solution known to us.

Comment: Looks to me like at least two bugs - firstly, it gets stuck; secondly, interrupts are ignored because a future is not correctly handled (a livelock busy loop ensues). The problem is related to com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner.waitForAll(CacheUpdateRunner.java:184)

Comment: I faced the same issue even when using the single Monitor. Issue got rectified by just restarting the machine. Strange and weird.. But somehow, my problem got resolved

Comment: I have similar issue on Windows. After some random time intellij stops responding to mouse clicks while it works fine in all other apps. Only log off/log on to Windows fixes the issue.

Comment: @LeonidVysochyn wierd. Haven't ran into that. I had some performance issues where IDEA froze, or simply became unresponsive, but that were cause by the PC. Have you tried checking your system resources in the task manager? CPU/RAM/hard drive if they aren't 100% used..

Comment: @Dropout I have discovered that in fact all java applications stop responding to mouse clicks after some time. Even the Java applet in Control panel. I have updated to the latest JDK 1.8_131 but it still does not help. So probably this is some global java related issue rather than Intellij related. Reinstalling mouse driver did not help and all non-java apps work fine.

Comment: Resizing PyCharm window fixed the problem on Mac also o_O

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue on a Mac today. I noticed this only happens with the external mouse and not the trackpad. The mouse works on every other app, except for Intellij. I tried restarting IntelliJ but it didn't help.

Finally, **unplugging the external mouse and plugging it back in** did the trick.

Comment: +1 I can confirm that on MacOS Android Studio can also experience the same problem with an external mouse (it is using the IntelliJ platform after all). App restart did not help, Mac restart did not help (weirdly enough), however unplugging the mouse (and then plugging it back) did solve the problem.

Comment: It was happening to me right now on macOs Monterey. The trackpad was not working, I unplugged the USB mouse and plugged it back in after this comment: it's working again.

Comment: This is just annoying, I did down grade to 2022.2 but still didn't work and ONLY solution is use trackpad, with external mouse, you can't do anything in Inetllij

Comment: You saved me a reboot, sir.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting my computer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem today (May 2021) on my macOS with Intellij Community 2021.1.1. For me, it's related to my external USB mouse. Plugging back again did the trick.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, both the external mouse and the internal trackpad was unusable with IDEA. Unplugging and replugging the external mouse solved the problem.

Comment: If you have a bluetooth mouse, just disconnecting or restarting wont help. I had to unregister('Forget the device') and register the device again.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar problem after a major update. All of the mouse events are not working and the shortcuts are also not responding. Only the `Alt+F` and arrows key can open main menu, then `Enter` key can select the sub menu.

I noticed that I had once **changed the boot Java runtime of the IDE**. Then I reset the JVM to default, the problem solved.

#### Instructions

1. Press `Alt+H` to open the **Help** menu and select the **Find Action** sub item. Because the mouse is not responding and `Ctrl+Shift+A` is not working. You may only open the dialog by main menu.
2. Type `Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE` action. Use arrows key to select the item. Use `Enter` to open the dialog.
3. Use `Tab` key to focus on the `Use Default Runtime`, Press `Enter` to confirm.
4. Wait for WebStorm to restart with the new runtime.

Everything will be fine after restart.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My solution is just to wait. Sharing my today's experience, I launched the software in the morning and I found my Intellij finally worked well in the evening. I didn't check when it was well in between, but I guess it should cost 1 or 2 hours. If it's not working for you, you can try to launch eclipse then wait. Good luck for you!

Comment: Very funny your post, I first **up-voted** it just because it made me laugh. Than I researched a bit more and as I came back to PHP-Storm it just worked. So you where right with just wait ... hopefully more problems could be solved that way :D ... if I could I would have up-voted it again.

Comment: LOL , I paid for the "All Product Pack" . What a shame. Webstorm has more issues than IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems to work just to wait a while, as proposed by @ser3771751, it seems to be a problem with memory. In the lower right corner is an indicator for memory consumption, alt least in PhpStorm, klicking on that icon will free up memory an the UI will be responsive again. At least it worked for me. As it does not happen to much I haven't verified it yet.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure anymore, I guess it was just coincidence, as today phpStorm didn't react on mouse clicks (hover still works), I tried to do the same but it didn't work. I also tried to enable and disable File > Power Save Mode, but that didn't work neither. So far, the best option is still have a break and come back a few minutes later.

Comment: Today this happened to me for a first time. The only thing that helped was clicking on memory indicator. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl+Tab. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am a Korean user. It seems that the problem may be in the language-related part.

I use IntelliJ on a mac and I run into that problem often.

In my case, the solution is to `open a context window by right-clicking` on the problematic window and then `press the Caps Lock(if you use Korean Keyboard => 한/A) key`.

[image]
[image]

This answer may be grammatically odd due to Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer in case it helps someone facing a similar problem. (as the question is very old now) I have faced a similar problem if my code happens to have some directory with a lot of huge non-code files.

As the IDE keeps doing indexing for a long time. I remember working with [Enron dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus) in one of my python projects. And I just couldn't do anything at all. Restarting didn't help as well.

Does the problematic window have such directories in its code?

If yes, do this:

1. Restart IntelliJ.
2. Once it comes up and starts indexing, right click on such folder.
3. Select `Mark Directory as`->`Excluded`

Doing so will skip this directory while indexing, and will save a lot of time, processing and system's memory every time. Now I always do it for all resources directories.

Answer (score 0):

Even after re-installing everything and reseting nvram. I had continued to have the problem.

Clearing the Java cache using the Java control panel applet did the trick.  I had to do this even though I had uninstalled and reinstalled Java.

Another weird symptom I had was that in the Java control panel applet, if I unplugged and plugged back in my mouse receiver (usb), then I could click on buttons that were in the current "frame" and above, but not child frames.   However, this is not solely a USB issue because my mac built in trackpad was not working either.

Comment: I've experienced the exactly same (2021 now). It turned out that my Microsoft Sculpt Desktop caused the issue. Java apps are impacted the most with mouse clicking not working at all. Another set of Microsoft Sculpt Desktop at office works fine! I suspect that the receiver became faulty.

Comment: I have a sculpt mouse as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in VNC.
And found gnome-shell is using more cpu resource than before (>15%). 
The workaround is to kill the process of "gnome-shell".

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it is helpful to address both what new information your answer brings, and how the passage of time may affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the windows subsystem for Linux. There is what I did:

```
1. remove .idea folder
2. remove everything under C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains
```

now it's working fine with no issues

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this with Phpstorm 1221.3.1 on Intel Mac running Montery 1221.3.1 out of the blue.

Clicks on my mouse or my touchpad were not working on Phpstorm.   Reboot didn't fix...  but Unplugging and replugging my mouse back in fixed for everything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. My solution was to uninstall Java:

- `brew uninstall java java8 openjdk jenv` -- i had all these
- reboot
- now Rider works (using builtin java)

```
MacOS Monterey v12.2.1

JetBrains Rider 2021.3.1
Build #RD-213.5744.299, built on December 8, 2021
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced the similar issue, unplugging and plugging back resolved it.

Comment: What device(s) did you disconnect and reconnect?